# Problems with servicestack and typelinks

Tags: c#, types, servicestack

I have problems with gerenating types, it returns error 
500 - InvalidDataException

I can't understand whats wrong as my project builds fine and API works.

None of the types works except the metadata

https://testapi.bokamera.se/types/

Please help as i'm stuck

Regards Kristian

Here you can see my call using Postman
[image]

and here you can see my DTO causing the problem

```
namespace BokaMera.API.ServiceModel.Dtos
{
[Route("/customfields",
    Verbs = "GET",
    Summary = "Find custom fields",
    Notes =
        "Find custom fields defined for the bookings that the current admin user is authorized to view."
    )]
[ApiResponse(HttpStatusCode.Unauthorized, "You were unauthorized to call this service")]
[ApiResponse(HttpStatusCode.Forbidden, "You have too low privilegies to call this service")]
public class CustomFieldQuery :
    QueryBase<CustomFieldConfig, CustomFieldQueryResponse>
{
    [ApiMember(
        Description =
            "One or multiple id's of custom fields to find",
        ParameterType = "query",
        IsRequired = false)]
    public int[] Ids { get; set; }

    [ApiMember(
        Description =
            "Company id to find custom fields for",
        ParameterType = "query",
        IsRequired = false)]
    public Guid? CompanyId { get; set; }

    [ApiMember(
        Description =
            "Table to which the custom field belongs to",
        ParameterType = "query",
        IsRequired = false)]
    public string Table { get; set; }

    [ApiMember(
        Description =
            "Active or removed fields, empty parameter includes both",
        ParameterType = "query",
        IsRequired = false)]
    public bool? Active { get; set; }
}

public class CustomFieldQueryResponse
{
    [ApiMember(Description = "Custom field id")]
    public int Id { get; set; }

    [ApiMember(Description = "Reference to company that owns the custom field configuration")]
    public Guid CompanyId { get; set; }

    [ApiMember(Description = "Group id")]
    public int? GroupId { get; set; }

    [ApiMember(Description = "Config id")]
    public int ConfigId { get; set; }

    [ApiMember(Description = "Configuration name. Example: \"Number of persons\".")]
    public string ConfigName { get; set; }

    [ApiMember(Description = "Field width. Example: 20")]
    public int Width { get; set; }

    [ApiMember(Description = "Column in database where to store the information. Example: \"TextField1\"")]
    public string Column { get; set; }

    [ApiMember(Description = "Custom field description. Example: \"For how many persons is this booking?\"")]
    public string Description { get; set; }

    [ApiMember(Description = "Data field of custom field. Valid values are: TextBox, ... Example: \"TextBox\"")]
    public string DataType { get; set; }

    [ApiMember(Description = "Default value of the field. Example: \"3\"")]
    public string DefaultValue { get; set; }

    [ApiMember(Description = "Determines if the field is required to have a value or not")]
    public bool Required { get; set; }

    [ApiMember(Description = "Error message shown to the user if the field data is required but not entered")]
    public string MandatoryErrorMessage { get; set; }

    [ApiMember(Description = "Max lenght of the field")]
    public int MaxLength { get; set; }

    [ApiMember(Description = "")]
    public bool MultipleLineText { get; set; }

    [ApiMember(Description = "Regular expression used for validation of the field")]
    public string RegEx { get; set; }

    [ApiMember(Description = "Error message shown if the regular expression validation failed")]
    public string RegExErrorMessage { get; set; }

    [ApiMember(Description = "If the custom field is active or have been removed")]
    public bool Active { get; set; }

    [ApiMember(Description = "Table to which the field belongs")]
    public string Table { get; set; }

    [ApiMember(Description = "")]
    public List<CustomFieldLookupResponse> Values { get; set; }
}


[Alias("V_FreeFieldFieldLookUp")]
public class CustomFieldLookupResponse
{
    [PrimaryKey]
    [Alias("FieldLookupId")]
    public int? Id { get; set; }

    [Alias("FreeFieldId")]
    public int CustomFieldId { get; set; }

    [Alias("FieldlookupActive")]
    public bool? Active { get; set; }

    [Alias("FieldLookupGroupId")]
    public int GroupId { get; set; }

    [Alias("FieldlookupSortOrder")]
    public int? SortOrder { get; set; }

    [Alias("FieldlookupValue")]
    public string Value { get; set; }
}




//Used when sending in values on a DTO request object to the services to save on the tables.
public class CustomFieldDataValue
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Column { get; set; }
    public string Value { get; set; }

}


//Used to list all values on a DTO response object
public class CustomFieldData
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Column { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }
    public string Value { get; set; }
}

//Used when post or put values for different DTOS, see example Resource Dtos 
public class AddCustomField
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Value { get; set; }

}
```

}

And my service

```
namespace BokaMera.API.ServiceInterface.Services
{
public class CustomFieldService : AppServiceBase
{
    public IAutoQueryDb AutoQuery { get; set; }

    [Authenticate]
    [RequiredRole(Role.ApplicationAdmin)]
    public object Get(CustomFieldQuery request)
    {
        // Get the autoquery that we will append to
        var q = AutoQuery.CreateQuery(request, Request.GetRequestParams());

        // The user can only see his/her own time exceptions
        q = q.Where(te => te.CompanyId == UserSession.CompanyId);

        // Execute counts and return the query response
        var response = AutoQuery.Execute(request, q);
        return response;
    }
}
```

}

Comment: Are you using the latest v4.0.62 release? If you are please provide the full Exception StackTrace, we have no way of identifying the issues with only this Description.

Comment: HI, i dont know how to get the full exception stacktrace as it only returns error 500 when calling it. Please guide me. I will check what version. Regards Kristian

Comment: Upgrade to the latest v4.0.62 if you haven't already it will resolve your issue if you were on v4.0.58. If not [set DebugMode](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/wiki/Debugging#debugmode) to see if that shows any more info about the error, otherwise check [?debug=requestinfo](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/wiki/Debugging#request-info) to see if you have any **startupErrors**.

Comment: Thx very much! I have now upgraded but ran into problems with all my AutoQuery not comiling. Giving me a lot of errors. I will post a new thread about this. Thx!!!

Comment: I have now tried to upgrade to v4.0.62 but still the same blank page and no more error details. Also tried ?debug=requestinfo but didn't have any startupErrors. Also set DebugMode didn't give me any change

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you were on v4.0.58, it had an issue with Add ServiceStack Reference which can be resolved by upgrading to any release after that.

The issue with your DTOs was because they contained illegal `"` character in the Metadata attributes, i.e:

```
[ApiMember(Description = "Configuration name. Example: \"Number of persons\".")]
public string ConfigName { get; set; }
```

We validate metadata attributes to prevent an attacker from potentially injecting illegal data that they could use to generate malicious in Service consumers.

So to prevent the error you can remove double quotes (`"`) from strings in your metadata attributes, replacing them with single quotes (`'`) is fine, otherwise you can disable token verification in your AppHost.Configure() with:

```
NativeTypesFeature.DisableTokenVerification = true;
```

Incidentally Exception details from Code Generation will be more visible in the next release from [this commit](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/commit/eb64c188573faa0cf39fb2da9c007d6303cb220d), so it will be clearer to tell what the error was.

---

#### Deprecated Warnings

Please take note of the Deprecation messages (also covered in Breaking changes in each Release Notes). `QueryBase` has been renamed to `QueryDb`, e.g:

```
public class CustomFieldQuery :
    QueryDb<CustomFieldConfig, CustomFieldQueryResponse>
```

Also it's better for your custom AutoQuery implementations to pass the entire `IRequest` instead of just the parameters, e.g:

```
var q = AutoQuery.CreateQuery(request, base.Request);
```

This has the same behavior except it also allows this AutoQuery Service to participate in [Multitenancy requests](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/wiki/Multitenancy).

Comment: I have renewed my license and upgraded to latest version v4.0.62 but it didn't help. Still only a blank page and error 500 InvalidDataException returned. 
Please help

Comment: @Krillehbg Make sure all packages have been upgraded to v4.0.62, then see if it works for a single Request DTO using ?include queryString e.g /types/csharp?include=RequestDTO1,DTO2,etc try it on different Request DTOs until you can find the one causing the error, when you do please update your question to include the full class definition of the Request DTO so I can run it locally to reproduce the issue.

Comment: Thx @mythz for helping me. I tried to use the ?include=MyDtoName but it gives me the same error whatever dto im trying with. Even if i trying a dto that doesn't exists (just a random name). See above using Postman and also my DTO. But the error seems to be more generic

Comment: @Krillehbg if all packages have upgraded to v4.0.62? Then try commenting out Service implementations so they're not included in the generated DTOs. If you find the Service with the issue please update your questions with its DTO definitions. If you still can't find it I'll need a stand alone project I can run that repro's the issue, the Service implementations don't affect code generation so you can leaves those out and just throw NotImplementedExceptions.

Comment: Hi, thx. When you say commenting out service implementation, you mean to comment out all code within the service and not the DTO?

Comment: @Krillehbg yeah just the implementation, the DTOs on their own aren't included if they're not part of a Service.

Comment: I managed to get it working by disabling one of the services. I have provided that code for DTO and service in my case above if you maybe can see whats wrong? THX!!

Comment: @Krillehbg The issue was using `"` in your metadata attributes, See my updated answer for workarounds.